# Error in example source code in Solidity docs

Tags: error

Newbie here. I'm trying to deploy [the example purchase contract shown on the Ethereum site here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/solidity-by-example.html#safe-remote-purchase) to the online Remix Solidity compiler at http://remix.ethereum.org/.

But when I copy/paste the example code as written, I get the following error message.

Error message

> browser/purchase.sol:62:25: Warning: Using contract member "balance" inherited from the address type is deprecated. Convert the contract to "address" type to access the member, for example use "address(contract).balance" instead.

```
 seller.transfer(this.balance);
                    ^----------^
```

Can anyone help correct my code below? I've shown my work and two things I've already tried unsuccessfully.

purchase.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract Purchase {
    uint public value;
    address public seller;
    address public buyer;
    enum State { Created, Locked, Inactive }
    State public state;

    // Ensure that `msg.value` is an even number.
    // Division will truncate if it is an odd number.
    // Check via multiplication that it wasn't an odd number.
    constructor() public payable {
        seller = msg.sender;
        value = msg.value / 2;
        require((2 * value) == msg.value, "Value has to be even.");
    }

    modifier condition(bool _condition) {
        require(_condition);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyBuyer() {
        require(
            msg.sender == buyer,
            "Only buyer can call this."
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier onlySeller() {
        require(
            msg.sender == seller,
            "Only seller can call this."
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier inState(State _state) {
        require(
            state == _state,
            "Invalid state."
        );
        _;
    }

    event Aborted();
    event PurchaseConfirmed();
    event ItemReceived();

    /// Abort the purchase and reclaim the ether.
    /// Can only be called by the seller before
    /// the contract is locked.
    function abort()
        public
        onlySeller
        inState(State.Created)
    {
        emit Aborted();
        state = State.Inactive;
        seller.transfer(this.balance); // original attempt, yields below error
        // seller.transfer(address(contract).balance); // first unsuccessful attempt to correct
        // address(contract).balance; // second unsuccessful attempt to correct
    }

    /// Confirm the purchase as buyer.
    /// Transaction has to include `2 * value` ether.
    /// The ether will be locked until confirmReceived
    /// is called.
    function confirmPurchase()
        public
        inState(State.Created)
        condition(msg.value == (2 * value))
        payable
    {
        emit PurchaseConfirmed();
        buyer = msg.sender;
        state = State.Locked;
    }

    /// Confirm that you (the buyer) received the item.
    /// This will release the locked ether.
    function confirmReceived()
        public
        onlyBuyer
        inState(State.Locked)
    {
        emit ItemReceived();
        // It is important to change the state first because
        // otherwise, the contracts called using `send` below
        // can call in again here.
        state = State.Inactive;

        // NOTE: This actually allows both the buyer and the seller to
        // block the refund - the withdraw pattern should be used.

        buyer.transfer(value);
        seller.transfer(this.balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you to change `this.balance` to `address(this).balance`.

Answer (score 1):

Summary from comments.

The corrected code is as follows.

purchase.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract Purchase {
    uint public value;
    address public seller;
    address public buyer;
    enum State { Created, Locked, Inactive }
    State public state;

    // Ensure that `msg.value` is an even number.
    // Division will truncate if it is an odd number.
    // Check via multiplication that it wasn't an odd number.
    constructor() public payable {
        seller = msg.sender;
        value = msg.value / 2;
        require((2 * value) == msg.value, "Value has to be even.");
    }

    modifier condition(bool _condition) {
        require(_condition);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyBuyer() {
        require(
            msg.sender == buyer,
            "Only buyer can call this."
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier onlySeller() {
        require(
            msg.sender == seller,
            "Only seller can call this."
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier inState(State _state) {
        require(
            state == _state,
            "Invalid state."
        );
        _;
    }

    event Aborted();
    event PurchaseConfirmed();
    event ItemReceived();

    /// Abort the purchase and reclaim the ether.
    /// Can only be called by the seller before
    /// the contract is locked.
    function abort()
        public
        onlySeller
        inState(State.Created)
    {
        emit Aborted();
        state = State.Inactive;
        //seller.transfer(this.balance); // throws error
        seller.transfer(address(this).balance); // fixes error
    }

    /// Confirm the purchase as buyer.
    /// Transaction has to include `2 * value` ether.
    /// The ether will be locked until confirmReceived
    /// is called.
    function confirmPurchase()
        public
        inState(State.Created)
        condition(msg.value == (2 * value))
        payable
    {
        emit PurchaseConfirmed();
        buyer = msg.sender;
        state = State.Locked;
    }

    /// Confirm that you (the buyer) received the item.
    /// This will release the locked ether.
    function confirmReceived()
        public
        onlyBuyer
        inState(State.Locked)
    {
        emit ItemReceived();
        // It is important to change the state first because
        // otherwise, the contracts called using `send` below
        // can call in again here.
        state = State.Inactive;

        // NOTE: This actually allows both the buyer and the seller to
        // block the refund - the withdraw pattern should be used.

        buyer.transfer(value);
        //seller.transfer(this.balance); // throws error
        seller.transfer(address(this).balance); // fixes error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute balance is associated with a particular address and not the contract per se. When you are saying this.balance, it is trying to call the balance property of the contract, but instead it should be address(this).balance. This would give you access to the balance at the contract address.